# How can I play my Venus Special without hurting my fingers?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, fretboard

I have a Venus Special. It looks good but it is hard to play. My fingers hurt while playing the guitar.

What is the solution?

Comment: For how long have you been playing? If it's your first attempt at playing guitar it's normal that it hurts your fingertips until you get calouses developed.

Comment: It might help to get new strings or a lighter gauge.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the only solution is to continue to play. Your fingers will develop calluses and stop hurting after a few weeks (for some people it may be a couple months, it varies). Just make sure that after you have developed your calluses, you continue to play, because after a few days of not playing they will deteriorate and go away, leaving you at square one again.

Edit: I was addressing the question asked, not the title of the question. I don't really see a correlation between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting flat wound strings, which are much smoother than round wound strings. You should also try different gauges of string to see if you find one easier to play than another. Light gauge strings can be easier on your fingers since you don't have to press as hard.